# Simple C# output

Tags: c#, arrays, console-output

So I have been playing around with C# lately and I don't understand output formatting.

```
using System;

namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int[] Numbers = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Numbers[i] = r.Next(101);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("index {0} holds number {0}", i,Numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
[image: Code]

My expected output was `index i holds number Number[i]`. So can anyone explain what to change, or link me with a good C# page on output formatting topic.
I know there is a way to do it in 2 lines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change

```
Console.WriteLine("index {0} holds number {0}", i, Numbers[i]);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("index {0} holds number {1}", i, Numbers[i]);
```

Reason: Your indices (in the format string) reference the parameters *after the string* in zero-based index order. So {0} for the first parameter after the string, {1} for the second, {2} if you have a third etc.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

edit:
You can reference the parameters multiple times in your format String, too. E.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "index {0} holds number {1} (Numbers[{0}] == {1})", i, Numbers[i]);
```

This also is equivalent to

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
    "index {0} holds number {1} (Numbers[{0}] == {1})", i, Numbers[i]));
```

Comment: Oh, weird... Thought the {0} was a placeholder for numbers, like %d in java.

Comment: @destroyergm No, actually the String.Format function will automatically call `ToString()` on each of the parameters. So the type is irrelevant. edit: although the type could implement `IFormattable` for some special format strings. But still, the order of parameters determines their index.

Answer (score 5):

Your second print is wrong. You use `string.Format` but you don't bind the second parameter.

It should be:

```
Console.WriteLine( "index {0} holds number {1}", i, Numbers[i] );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.WriteLine("index {0} holds number {1}", i, Numbers[i] );
```